# error installing WWW::Curl::Easy "Cannot build Constants" MacOS

Tags: macos, perl, curl

I'm trying to install the WWW::Curl::Easy module on MacOS10.12.4 and it fails stating "Cannot find curl.h - cannot build constants file".

Curl-config in /usr/bin has an includedir of /usr/include, which does not exist.  I checked the Makefile with the perl module, and it lists several other locations it looks, such as /usr/local/include, /usr/local, etc.  Those didn't exist, but I made them and copied the curl.h that comes with XCode into them.

I still receive the same error.  Here is the log:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7043 on perl 5.016000 built for darwin-2level
Work directory is /Users/thisUser/.cpanm/work/1493902651.14410
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/curl
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching WWW::Curl::Easy () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on WWW::Curl::Easy
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz
Entering WWW-Curl-4.17
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (6.63_02)
Configuring WWW-Curl-4.17
Running Makefile.PL
Locating required external dependency bin:curl-config... found at /usr/bin/curl-config.
The version is libcurl 7.51.0
Cannot find curl.h - cannot build constants files  - see Makefile.PL at Makefile.PL line 96.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for WWW-Curl-4.17. See /Users/thisUser/.cpanm/work/1493902651.14410/build.log for details.
```

I've done my best searches here and on Google, and not finding an answer. I didn't have this issue when I installed this on my last Mac, so not sure what was changed.

Comment: I think it's because you haven't installed `libcurl`'s dev files. WWW::Curl::Easy's installer needs to extract definitions of constants from `curl.h`, and `curl.h` isn't usually installed by installing an OS's `libcurl` package.

Comment: (If I had to pick between WWW::Curl::Easy and Net::Curl::Easy, I'd use the latter. It's not that I know anything wrong about WWW::Curl::Easy, it's just that I have experience with Net::Curl::Easy, and it was written as an improvement to WWW::Curl:Easy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular error seems to be because the XCode command line tools were not installed.  I followed the instructions here: https://superuser.com/questions/995360/missing-usr-include-in-os-x-el-capitan

This still resulted in an error, but it is different and possibly unrelated to this one, so I am considering this question resolved.

Comment: Yes and no. The newest Xcode stuff from Apple fubars the module you want to install, because it references old-ish "stuff." Sorry for the short version. You _can_ solve it by installing an old gcc (4.8, I think), but I would rather fire up an VM if I were you.

Comment: One other solution would be - of course - to ask those Qual-guys to pay me to rewrite their (?) script so that it conforms to modern standards. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and then install curl (`brew install curl`) which will help *a little*, but you'll probably run into compilation problems.

I'm no big fan of the [WWW::Curl](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl) package, though, so might I ask what you are trying to achieve? There are way better "I want to access the interwebz"-packages out there. :)

Comment: It's a package that I use when making API calls to Qualys.  I'm no expert, and the example code I found uses it, so that's what I rolled with.

Comment: Can you link to the example code, or otherwise post it somewhere (pastebin, gist etc.)? If so, I can help you rewrite it using a bit more modern packages. :)

Comment: Here is the address of the example I used: https://github.com/Qualys/community/tree/master/fetchreport

Comment: @Pete: Ok. This was much more than I anticipated for a rewrite. :) Plus, I have no way of testing a rewrite, so my suggestion is that you install Linux on a VM and take it from there. The problem seems to be with newer version of gcc that comes with OSX. Sorry. :(

Comment: Part of the issue is that I didn't realize that XCode doesn't include the command line developer tools anymore: https://superuser.com/questions/995360/missing-usr-include-in-os-x-el-capitan

Though now I'm just getting an error for a different missing file (curlver.h)